# what is the problem withe my Retrofit Code in my Android App?

Tags: android, rest, api, kotlin, retrofit

Hi All I want to know what is the problem with my code 
I'm trying to run this Kotlin-Android app using retrofit but it is crashing and app doesn't start

```
package com.mammoth.retrofitkotlin

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        var API: API = retrofit.create(API::class.java)
        var call = API.calldata()
        var item = call.enqueue(object : Callback<model> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<model>, t: Throwable) {

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<model>, response: Response<model>) {
                var xx = response.body()!!.title
                txtView.text = xx
            }


        })

    }

}
```

i created this interface

```
package com.mammoth.retrofitkotlin

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET


interface API {

     @GET("posts/1")

     fun calldata() : Call<model>

}
```

and this is model class

```
package com.mammoth.retrofitkotlin

data class model (var userId : String,var id : String,var title : String,var body : String)
```

please what is wrong in my code

Comment: May you provide exception stack trace (from console/logcat)?

Comment: at com.mammoth.retrofitkotlin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)

Comment: Add whole stacktrace to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/) you have to add Java 8 compatibility in `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Remember also about `INTERNET` permission in Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--  Add this one:  -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
```

Comment: the problem was that i didn't add Java 8 compatibilty

it is working now

Comment: but i want to know more about the problem and understand issue

Comment: Base on the issue in OkHttp: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3280 the latest version requires Java 8 and proper (rather newer) version of Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: can you please help me with this problem ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683044/problem-while-retrieving-data-from-firebase-firestore-collection